# Get more than 1000 datasets from an Azure Table Storage

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I've an Azure Function to perform some operations on the datasets in an Azure Table Storage.

Since grouping is not working in Azure Table Storages, I have to fetch all datasets in my table and perform the operations I want (grouping, filtering) in my C# code.

But each query retrieves only the top 1000 datasets.
How can I get all my datasets - or iterating over the table in bulks of 1000 to get all datasets at the end?

```
TableQuery<Models.product_item> query = new TableQuery<Models.product_item>()
          .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, myPartitionKey));

var queryResult = myTable.ExecuteQuery(query);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your query did not complete within certain limits (max. 5 seconds, max. 1000 rows, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Query-Timeout-and-Pagination?redirectedfrom=MSDN)), you'll receive a `ContinuationToken` in your result object. Pass this token to another query to continue your first query and get the next bunch of rows.

This extension method does the job for you:

```
public static class QueryExtensions
{
    public static async Task<IEnumerable<TElement>> ExecuteQueryAllElementsAsync<TElement>(this CloudTable table, TableQuery<TElement> tableQuery)
        where TElement : ITableEntity, new()
    {
        TableContinuationToken continuationToken = default(TableContinuationToken);
        var results = new List<TElement>(0);
        tableQuery.TakeCount = 500;

        do
        {
            //Execute the next query segment async.
            var queryResult = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(tableQuery, continuationToken);

            //Set exact results list capacity with result count.
            results.Capacity += queryResult.Results.Count;
            results.AddRange(queryResult.Results);

            continuationToken = queryResult.ContinuationToken;

        } while (continuationToken != null);

        return results;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in your code like

```
var queryResult = await myTable.ExecuteQueryAllElementsAsync(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Probably to avoid long running query.

There are other limits wich you can read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Query-Timeout-and-Pagination?redirectedfrom=MSDN