# Get complete table with all datasets from Azure Table Storage with v4 Function Apps in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0, azure-table-storage

With older versions of .NET and Azure Function Apps v2 it was possible to get all datasets from an Azure Table Storage table using (among other things) a TableContinuationToken:
[Get more than 1000 datasets from an Azure Table Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60019560/get-more-than-1000-datasets-from-an-azure-table-storage)

Since the underlying Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table packages are deprecated:

**What is the new, current way in an .NET 6 based v4 Azure Function App to get all datasets from a table in an Azure Table Storage?**

Comment: Have you looked at `Azure.Data.Tables` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/data.tables-readme?view=azure-dotnet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reproduced the issue in my environment and able to fetch the data list.

Thanks @`Gaurav Mantri` for the comment.

1. create a storage account and table in azure.
   [image]

I used the below code and able to fetch the data list

```
private void tableInsert()
        {

            CloudStorageAccount storage_Account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageAccount_connectionString);
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storage_Account.CreateCloudTableClient();
            CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("table1");


            for (int ctr = 0; ctr < 1000; ctr++)
            {
                EmployeeEntity employeeEntity = new EmployeeEntity("Fname"+ctr, "LName"+ctr)
                {
                    Email = "something@something.com",
                    PhoneNumber = "123456789"

                };

                TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(employeeEntity);
                table.ExecuteAsync(insertOperation);
            }
           
        }
```

for fetching

```
 public async Task<List<TableEntity>> GetList()
        {
            
            CloudTable table = await GetTableAsync();
            
            TableQuery<TableEntity> query = new TableQuery<TableEntity>();
            List<TableEntity> results = new List<TableEntity>();
            TableContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
            do
            {
                TableQuerySegment<TableEntity> queryResults = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, continuationToken);
                continuationToken = queryResults.ContinuationToken;
                results.AddRange(queryResults.Results);
            } while (continuationToken != null);
            return results;
        }
        private async Task<CloudTable> GetTableAsync()
        {
            
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageAccount_connectionString);
            
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("table1");
            await table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
            return table;
        }
```

[image]

Reference taken from [Azure Tables client library for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/data.tables-readme?view=azure-dotnet)